# Detecting circular loop in concurrent queue

Tags: algorithm, concurrency, queue

I have a concurrent queue of connections. There is a ping task that periodically goes through all available connections in the queue to execute a ping and at the same time an application can ask for a connection from the queue for its use.

What is a good way in detecting circular loop so that ping task can complete its current execution?

**EDIT:**

Example: Assume concurrent queue has connections A,B and C.

There is a ping task which iterates through the queue. So in this example it will do `A.ping()`, `B.ping()` and `C.ping()`. Now there is an external class which also requests for a connection from the queue while the ping task is also iterating over the queue. So assume A.ping() has finished and `externalClass.getConnection()` will return `A`. By the time ping task finishes C.ping(), `externalClass.releaseConnection(A)` happens. Now the queue's order is `B,C and A`. So the ping task will find A again after finishing C.ping() at which point the task has to decide A has already been pinged and should finish current execution.

Comment: Please give an example circumstance where the circular loop happens

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you don't have a circular loop.

A circular loop is when you have a linked list that points back to itself. You merely have a queue that as you step through it might have another thread add repeated elements to the end of the queue.

The way to detect a circular loop is to use a `hashtable`, before each `Ping()` you check if the connection already exists in the connection, if it does then you just move on to the next element, if it doesn't exist then you add it to the `hashtable` and then you call your `Ping` operation to the server.

Or you can just have your initial `ping` operation make a snapshot of the queue at that exact time and not step over it.

With that said, something is very wrong with your queue if you can have two different callers get the same `A` result off the queue.

The correct way to do this code is to have two separate lists, one is a queue of connections for requests such as `externalClass.getConnection()` and the other is the list of connections for `Ping`. Whatever your `Ping` operation is doing it really shouldn't impact anything that any external class is doing with it's connection, For example assuming `connection` is a `sql connection` then `Ping` should execute something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 1
```

And nothing more, that will then mean your connection remains alive. as you are likely implementing this because the connections are being idle too long and closing themselves.. which in that case you really shouldn't because pretty much any flavor of sql dbms supports connection pooling which does exactly what you're trying to do. Unless you want to prevent more than Queue.Count concurrent connections at once by having the other executions wait (which in itself can be done much better ways that keeping a pool of open connections, such as a simple `int counter`)

Unless your keeping connections to different servers and trying to do some adhoc load balancing by rotating requests across several servers, then use my above solution with a list of all connections and a queue of available connections. The major benefit from this solution is that you can terminate all connections when the application closes even if they're currently processing requests.

**But, for completeness in answering your question:**

If you *did* have a circular loop it would look like this: `A -> B -> C -> A` where each element would point to the next in the list and not just be elements in a `queue`. A good example is you Ping server `A` which pings server `B` which pings server `C` which then pings `A` and you would detect it as follows:

The simple way to detect circular loops is to run two (or multiple) iterations through it at once, we'll call them X and Y.

For every second time you step (or `.Ping()` in your context) X, you step Y once. You might want to make a new method such as `Visit` rather than calling your `Ping` so that ping isn't called many times within the loop.

Assuming the queue looks like `A, B, C, A, B...`

After a few steps X will look like: `A, B, C, A` while Y will look like `A, B`. What you do is you **don't** store the entire history, you only look at the current values, so when you step in X you check if the new value matches the current value of Y, thus we will eventually always get to a collision.

This isn't the fastest or most efficient way to detect cyclic loops, but it is the most simple and if your loops will generally be small it is easier than storing a historical list of past routes (which in some cases requires significant changes to code). There are much more efficient algorithms that can be used for when your loops are more than 20 steps long (they're designed to deal with complex branching trees and the like). It is important to recognize that the worst case for this implementation will be a prime number of looping elements.

But you can improve performance on average by just expanding this further to have a `Z` iterator which steps once for every three `X` steps, at this point it's not really worth adding an additional one that steps every 5 `X` steps or 7 and so on (visiting the next incremental prime number with the creation of each new iterator).

Comment: The connections are not JDBC connection but thrift connections and ping() is thrift service method. And yes for now I am using a solution similar to you suggested, using HashSet instead of HashTable. But I am finding it difficult to understand your explanation of using 2 lists. I want the connections opened to be kept alive so that it can be used by the externalClass.

Answer (score 0):

Does your ping only ping each machine, or does it ping one machine, which pings the next, which pings the next, and then so on?

One way to solve this would be to have every machine keep track of if its already been pinged. If it has been, and it receives a new ping, it doesn't send the ping on again.

Another way to solve this would be to pass information about what machines the given ping packet has already seen along with it, and when a ping packet reaches a machine its already seen, it terminates.

Comment: The connection pool have all connections to the same machine which means yea all connections ping the same machine.

Comment: So what's the issue then? Does the machine ping you back when you ping it, or what? What is your meaning of a circular loop?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand what you were doing there, but to me it looks like the problem is because the Ping Task doesn't follow the enqueue/dequeue rule as the External Task does. So how about let the Ping Task first dequeue a connection, refresh its "ping value" and then enqueue it back?

If your objective is to guarantee that the External Task always gets the connection with the smallest ping value, then you might want to use a heap instead of a queue.